# 1-10 asterisks according to inserted values. Asterisks for each inserted value are printed in separate line

Tags: python

Write a program which takes exactly one line of text from the standard input. That line contains unspecified number of integer values separated by spaces. Program expects values between 1 and 10. Any other value or empty line is considered as incorrect input.
As a result your program prints to the standard output:
a) 1-10 asterisks according to inserted values. Asterisks for each inserted value are printed in separate line.
b) a string “Wrong input!” in case that the input is incorrect.

This is what I have:

```
n = input ("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ")

if n == "stop":
    print("No starts!")
try:
    n = int(n)
    if n>=1 and n<=10:
        for x in range (1, n+1):
            print (x * "*")

except:
   print("Wrong input")
```

However my professor wants me to be able to input any number from 1-10 on one line. And be able as a result to get the asterisk according to the number but each on different lines. So it's not a pyramid or any structure, just the asterisk according to the number on different lines each.

Comment: OK, so you have posted your homework question.  Now, what have you done?  It's unethical to ask us to do your homework for you.  You're expected to give it a go, then come to us if you have trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which includes your code and error message.

Comment: *"input even numbers on one line such as: 1, 5, 6, 9, 2"*. Ok, have you checked out [the str.split() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)?

Comment: Neither 1, 5 or 9 are even numbers

Comment: You'll need to convert the input string to a list of integers. Something like `n_list = list(map(int,n.split()))` will do that (obviously use whatever method you've been taught since you'll have to explain how it works). Once that list is validated (checking that each element in the list is between 1 and 10) then you'll want to loop through numbers 1 through 10: `for x in range(1,11):`. You can then test if `x in n_list` and print an asterisk or the number accordingly.

Comment: Could you explain that in a better way because I tried what you've suggested and I still can't print the asterisk if I put (example input 1, 5, 3) only works with single numbers. @JNevill

Comment: Yeah. The real trick here is that you need to take the input string `1 5 3` and turn it into a python list. `n_list = n.split()`. Give that a shot and then do a `print(n_list)` and you'll find the output is `['1','5','3']`. A list with three elements with the individual numbers you typed in. This is an important step that you were missing in your code.